# getting the current date through a event handler

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

the question said I need to get the current date and set it as default in the text box.

"Add an event handler for the Load event of the form. This event handler should get the current date to the Arrival Date in a text box as default values."

```
   DateTime ArrivalDate = DateTime.Parse(txtArrivalDate.Text);
  //calling the method

     DateTime currentDate = this.GetTodaysDate(ArrivalDate);
    txtArrivalDate.Text=currentDate.toString();

   // event handler
     private DateTime GetTodaysDate (DateTime ArrivalDate) {

        ArrivalDate = DateTime.Now;

        return ArrivalDate;


   }
```

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the Forms onload event handler signature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        txtArrivalDate.Text = today.ToString("dd / MM / yyyy");
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more detail explaining this answer instead of just the code? It doesn't help them understand what's going on if they just copy-paste what you wrote.